# The type or namespace name 'IClientValidatable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

How to solve this error from .net. I am using visual studio and building one project in it and getting this error. I am not able to resolve this error. please help me.

Comment: Are you using MVC?

Comment: yes I am using MVC.

Comment: Then try the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have not included `using System.Web.Mvc;`

Include this namespace at the top of your code.